# Is a student allowed to study Brahma Sutra?

Tags: brahma-sutras

I am a student at the University and am interested in the Brahma Sutra. I have made the pursuit of absolute knowledge of Brahman my life goal. But from the first verse of the Brahma sutra I am guessing that I am too young to read the Brahma Sutra. I have never had a family nor a job (apart from student jobs). Am I allowed to study the Brahma Sutra? Is there a gurukul in India where I can study it?

Comment: I didn't understand the point of the question. Who will prevent you from studying the Brahma Sutra? What has age got to do with it? Shankaracharya started writing his celebrated commentary on Brahma Sutra when he was 12 years old.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay I am reading George Thibaut's commentary. It says in the "The small Purvapaksha": A further objection is urged as that which has to precede the systematic enquiry into Brahman... Hence some prerequisite  must be indicated which has reference to the principal topic of the sastra.... and this prerequsite is just the knowledge of works... Reading this I thought that I first need to live a life before I am qualified to undertake study in Brahma Sutra.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. There is no age barrier to know about the path to moksha.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay thank you for your answer.